# Should this regex pattern throw an exception?

Tags: c#, regex

Should this regex pattern throw an exception? Does for me.

```
^\d{3}[a-z]
```

The error is: `parsing "^\d{3}[a" - Unterminated [] set.`

I feel dumb. I don't get the error. (My RegexBuddy seems okay with it.)

A little more context which I hope doesn't cloud the issue:

I am writing this for a CLR user defined function in SQL Server:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic=true)]
  public static SqlChars Match(
    SqlChars input,
    SqlString pattern,
    SqlInt32 matchNb,
    SqlString name,
    SqlBoolean compile,
    SqlBoolean ignoreCase,
    SqlBoolean multiline,
    SqlBoolean singleline
    )
  {
    if (input.IsNull || pattern.IsNull || matchNb.IsNull || name.IsNull)
      return SqlChars.Null; 

    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
      (compile.Value ? RegexOptions.Compiled : 0) |
      (ignoreCase.Value ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : 0) |
      (multiline.Value ? RegexOptions.Multiline : 0) |
      (singleline.Value ? RegexOptions.Singleline : 0);

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern.Value, options);
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(new string(input.Value));

    if (matches.Count == 0 || matchNb.Value > (matches.Count-1))
      return SqlChars.Null;

    Match match = matches[matchNb.Value];

    int number;
    if (Int32.TryParse(name.Value, out number))
    {
      return (number > (match.Groups.Count - 1)) ? 
        SqlChars.Null :
        new SqlChars(match.Groups[number].Value);
    }
    else
    {
      return new SqlChars(match.Groups[name.Value].Value);
    }
  }
```

Setting it up with

```
CREATE FUNCTION Match(@input NVARCHAR(max), @pattern NVARCHAR(8), @matchNb INT, @name NVARCHAR(64), @compile BIT, @ignoreCase BIT, @multiline BIT, @singleline BIT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [RegEx].[UserDefinedFunctions].[Match]
GO
```

And testing it with:

```
SELECT dbo.Match(
  N'123x45.6789' --@input
, N'^\d{3}[a-z]' --@pattern
,0 --@matchNb
,0 --@name
,0 --@compile
,1 --@ignoreCase
,0 --@multiline
,1 --@singleline
)
```

Comment: Can we see the context in which you're using it?

Comment: are you trying to match 3 numbers followed by a lower case letter?   eg: 123a

Comment: @cory: Sure. I was trying to be succinct. Too succinct? :)

Comment: @David: Actually, I was trying to match three digits followed by \, . or -. To avoid weird characters, I reduced it to a simpler pattern, which still failed somehow...

Comment: Can you confirm via debug that new string(input.Value) == "^\d{3}[a-z]"?  I'm a little unfamiliar with SqlChars.  Something somewhere along the way seems to be truncating your pattern to 8 characters.  Do you have >8 character patterns that *do* work?

Comment: @Michael: Post your question in the form of an answer. You'll see it in my second update. You helped me spot my stupid, stupid error. I'll give you the points. As you can see, I force the pattern to a max of 8 chars, silently truncated...

Comment: But where are you forcing it to a max of 8 chars?

Comment: Wait, I see it now.  Let me clarify my answer.

Comment: That should do it... maybe it will help the next person out more quickly!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your CREATE FUNCTION statement you are delcaring @pattern as NVARCHAR(8).  This is truncating your pattern to 8 characters.